# <option> doesn't insert to <select>

Tags: php, html

Why other options aren't in ?

```
<select name="to">
    <?php
         foreach($students as $student) {
    ?>
           <option value="<?php echo($student['name'] . ' ' . $student['surname']); ?>"><?php echo($student["name"] . " " . $student["surname"]); ?></option>
           <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo($student['name']);?>">
           <input type="hidden" name="surname" value="<?php echo($student['surname']);?>">
    <?php
         }

         foreach($teachers as $teacher) {
    ?>
           <option value="<?php echo($teacher['name'] . ' ' . $teacher['surname']); ?>"><?php echo($teacher["name"] . " " . $teacher["surname"]); ?></option>
           <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo($student['name']);?>">
           <input type="hidden" name="surname" value="<?php echo($student['surname']);?>">
    <?php
         }
    ?>
</select>
```

That is how it looks:

```
<select name="to">
      <option value="BOBO BO">BOBO BO</option>
      <input type="hidden" name="name" value="BOBO">
      <input type="hidden" name="surname" value="BO">
      <option value="XD MAN">XD MAN</option>
      <input type="hidden" name="name" value="XD">
      <input type="hidden" name="surname" value="MAN">
      <option value="IVA OVOO">IVA OVOO</option>
      <input type="hidden" name="name" value="XD">
      <input type="hidden" name="surname" value="MAN">
      <option value="LOKO LOOKO">LOKO LOOKO</option>
      <input type="hidden" name="name" value="XD">
      <input type="hidden" name="surname" value="MAN">
</select>
```

And why is **XD MAN** under two another person?

I have to get name and surname separately, that is why I save them to hidden input.

Comment: I think that syntax is invalid. You can't have an input inside of the select tag.

Comment: So how can I print the name and the surname? I have to print them with foreach loop, but to option is bad, because I send with POST only select <option> to another page and I don't know, how to send the others option.

Comment: You have a copy+paste error. When you are looping `$teachers` then you need to access `$teacher['name']`

Comment: I didn't copy all of my code, I copied just important part.

Comment: It's not clear what you wanna achieve. _"I have to print them with foreach loop, but to option is bad, because I send with POST only select <option> to another page"_ - is a bit cryptical.

Comment: You really should be use an ID to reference a selection... instead of the string literal of the name variables.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your PHP code:

1.) In the second `foreach` you still use `$student` in the second and third echo. Thats why you get the same name again and again.
*BTW you don't have to use parenthesis with echo.*

2.) Like other people already commented on your question: The output is **invalid HTML** anyways, which is probably the reason why your browser is not displaying all `<option>`s correctly. You just cannot have `<input>`s inside of a `<select>`.
Why don't you just use some special character (lets say `+`) to separate the name and the surname in the `<option>`s value attribute and then use `explode('+',$_POST['to'])` (or `$_GET` respectively) when you get the results back on the server? This way you could get the name and surname separately.